# Is there a way to access ubuntu files from windows?

Tags: dual-boot

My laptop is dual boot
I was trying to update ubuntu but something went wrong , I think ubuntu is now corrupt from the inside out , I can no longer boot into it , I tried every possible solution but it either fails or shows countless errors . So I decided to save the files that are on it (it was my main OS , I have some very important files on it ) from windows if possible , then remove it completely and reinstall it .
So what's the best , safest and free way to get my files to windows ?

Comment: Do it from a live session. You can install software in Windows to read EXT4 file systems but it's notoriously unreliable and can further corrupt the exact data you want to retrieve.

Comment: +1 for "Do it from a live session" - I would only make clear that I mean for an **Ubuntu** live session for example booted from a USB pendrive.

Comment: "Ubuntu pendrive" = The installation media, in "Try ubuntu" mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access it on your Windows through -for instance- a USB to SATA adapter, you will need a software like explore2fs (portable edition [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/explore2fspe/) on sourceforge).
This is only if your Linux partition is still relatively intact and unencrypted!
In the case you had it encrypted (that's an option at install sometimes people don't really pay attention to), there's no other (easy) option than to boot on it and log in to copy the files on a USB stick.
Worst case scenario would be a damaged AND encrypted partition, chances of recovery would be extra thin (close to zero).